# Angular Forms, invalidate a form if a p-select is unchanged with the original value

Tags: angular, forms, reactive, form-control

my requirement is to disable the submit button until user changes any of the form control, the issue is the input fields which is a required field is easily handled, however the other control is a select control, and there are three options, based on settings, any of the three options is selected, if the user doesn't change the option in this select field then the submit button should remain disabled. is there any inbuilt validator that can assist for this? or if not any custom validator?
I have tried few validators but it didn't work out

Answer (score 0):

Adding Validators.required to your select control should be sufficient

Comment: it is passing the required validation because the select field is being populated in the ngOnInit, so basically the value is always selected, I just want to ensure that user doesnt hit Submit without changing the value.

Comment: add a custom validator which checks that the value of the select is different from the one in ngOnInit

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Form.valueChanges.subscribe(res=>{//your code here to enable and disable the submit button})` in reactive forms

this will help you to watch any change in the form